# Create map in R with better position of the legend

Tags: r

I have created a map with the following code

```
map = st_as_sf(map)


tm_shape(map) +
  tm_borders("grey", lwd = 1) +
  tm_fill("ratio") +
tm_compass(position = c("right", "bottom"))
```

Now the position of the legend is bad, I want it higher up, but not all the way up, or it will overlap with the title.

Comment: I've chopped your second Q out of the post, because if you even have a sniff of two questions here a moderator will slam you into oblivion. Try posting another question about the spacing - preferably with sample data we can run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do fine manual control of the legend with `legend.position` as two numbers:

```
tm_layout(legend.position=c(0.5,0))
```

where the numbers are the fraction of the way up or along the map to start the legend.